# Snappy vs Apt packages on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, snap, canonical

This is a highly speculative question concerning the future of Snaps on the upcoming Ubuntu 18.04; I'm hoping to get some insights/thoughts from the community/developers on the topic.

So far it seems that many of the default Gnome applications are already available as snaps:

- gnome-calculator
- gnome-calendar
- gnome-system-monitor
- gnome-font-viewer
- gnome-logs
- eog
- evince
- gedit
- libreoffice
- simple-scan

Do you expect that in a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04, the snappy versions will be installed by default?

If yes, do you believe that on a system update the apt versions will be replaced by the snappy versions?

**EDIT:** It seems that KDE Neon "plans on adopting Snaps by default for their rolling operating system" [source](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kubuntu-devel/2017-November/011488.html). Unfortunately I can't find a reference for Ubuntu Desktop.

Comment: This is a speculative question about a version of Ubuntu that's unsupported here, and, for both reasons, I think it's off-topic here.

Comment: I think you should ask this question on [Ubuntu Community Hub](https://community.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: It is indeed speculative but I don't think it is off-topic. There are other valid questions around this theme requesting more info on the Snappy transition.

Comment: The email forwarded to Kubuntu is here, so yes, the plan is to have core gnome apps as snaps. https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kubuntu-devel/2017-November/011488.html Keep in mind Ubuntu has a long history of overestimating it's resources per time frame..